# mediaquery not working when browser window is less than 900px wide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm trying to get the vertical piping for the about section to go away when the browser viewport is reduced to 990px or less wide.

Here's a fiddle of what I have, but can't get the `@mediaquery` to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8wsm7pfy/

Comment: I don't see any media query in your fiddle

Comment: Just realized it didn't make it in there, woops!
http://jsfiddle.net/8wsm7pfy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the `border-left`? If so, you need to override it. Just leaving it out won't do anything. Also, "990px or less" would need a `max-width` media query:

```
    @media (max-width: 990px){
       .about{
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 200px;
        border-left: none;
        }
    }
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8wsm7pfy/2/

You're also missing an end `</div>` tag in your first .